# Array of items with buttons

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm fairly new to MS Access (2007) and I have a quick question. I am building a form that is meant to help aid data entry on a changing schedule.

So I would like the form to work as follows. First the user enters in the number of trucks he will be recording that day. The form would grab those first X trucks off a schedule and create an item for each truck. Since the schedule can change, each item has an up/down arrow to move it around the schedule. The "Empty Lineset" is actually the caption of a button that would be changed to the truck's identifier when created. Pressing the button would bring the user to a different form to enter data on that truck.

The idea is for it to look something like this:

[image: Truck Lineup]

**So my question is** - Is there a way to create an array or something functionally like an array of these items. So if the user entered 6 trucks for the day, it would create 6 of these truck items.

The idea of an Array of items like this is pretty cool, but I'm not sure how to go about creating it. If anyone has any ideas or suggestions, please let me know.

Thanks guys

Comment: Sounds to me, and I could be totally wrong, like you need a multi-dimensional array.  I say this because you need the array to store both the Truck ID and the position in the array (since that position can change).  I'm not sure how to re-order an array if you don't have the original position indexed, which is why I think you'll need a multi-dimentional array.  Maybe someone else has a different idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to create what they called a control array.  Here's some example code that should get you started:

```
Private Sub UserForm_initialize()
Dim TBarray(0 To 5) As Control
Dim i As Integer
Dim intTop As Integer

intTop = 0
For i = 0 To 5
Set TBarray(i) = Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1", "TextBox" & i)
TBarray(i).Top = intTop + 20
TBarray(i).Text = "Name: " & TBarray(i).Name
intTop = intTop + 20
Next i

End Sub
```

I've done this before, but the code here is from:  [here](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/3525-control-arrays-collection-objects-visual-basic-applications.html)

Comment: This looks like a great place to start! Thank you. I'm still not very familiar with some of this lingo so half the problems are just finding out how to google a question. Thanks again