# Auto-Generate Textboxes with code in Access VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I tried using Auto Subs, but I can't understand that well..

I have Multiple (In this case 59) Textboxes/Buttons in a Form, everything with a **Click Event**. But in VBA I don't want to make every single one with code because I want to make the Form easy to control and use it to someone who doesn't code, and having **59 Click Subs** would be quite ugly and if I wanted to add more I would need to create in the VBA Code another Sub.

The real question is: **Is there some way to do Auto Code (Sub) for every Text/ Button with different variables?**

*E.G.:*

```
Text1_Click + Code -> Variable: 1
Text2_Click + Code -> Variable: 2
Text3_Click + Code -> Variable: 3   --> Text(?)_Click + Code -> Variable: ?
Text4_Click + Code -> Variable: 4
Text5_Click + Code -> Variable: 5
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Array of items with buttons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17888875/array-of-items-with-buttons)

Comment: You can use event sinking, essentially creating a code that inherits from the controls, then gives you the facility to modify the events, like on click

Comment: You could use a  [Control Array](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa241305(v=vs.60).aspx).  This allows one sub to handle many controls.

Comment: It's a little bit different from this one [Array of items](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17888875/array-of-items-with-buttons) because I only want to put the current textboxes with code, and not making new ones.

Comment: @destination-data: AFAIK, control arrays exist only in actual VB, not in Access / VBA.

Comment: Sorry!  @Andre good point, I'm a little rusty with MS Access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a VBA function and use it for each text box's *On Click* property: `=MyFunction()`

In your example, the text boxes are named `Text1` through `Text5` and it seems you want `Variable` to contain the number from the text box name.  It's easy to extract that number with `Mid()`.

```vb
Public Function MyFunction()
    Dim strControl As String
    Dim Variable As Variant

    strControl = Application.Screen.ActiveControl.Name
    Variable = Null
    If strControl Like "Text*" Then
        Variable = Val(Mid(strControl, 5))
    End If
    Debug.Print strControl & "_Click -> Variable: " & Nz(Variable, "Null")
End Function
```

If you want to extend that approach to numbered command buttons, include this ...

```vb
    If strControl Like "Command*" Then
        Variable = Val(Mid(strControl, 8))
    End If
```

If you need to assign the *On Click* property programmatically, loop through the controls and set each `.OnClick = "=MyFunction()"`

Comment: This worked perfectly and It's so easy to use it, Thank you @HansUp

Answer (score 1):

In your form have the buttons, and the following code

```
Option Explicit

Public colCustomControls As Collection

Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)

Dim ctl As Control
Dim clsCustom As clsCustomButton

    Set colCustomControls = New Collection

    For Each ctl In Me.Controls
        Set clsCustom = New clsCustomButton
        clsCustom.INITIALISE ctl
        colCustomControls.Add clsCustom
    Next ctl

End Sub
```

then a class called clsCustomButton

```
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents cbCustom As CommandButton

Public Sub INITIALISE(cb As CommandButton)
    Set cbCustom = cb
    cb.OnClick = "[Event Procedure]"
End Sub

Private Sub cbCustom_Click()
    Select Case cbCustom.Name
        Case "Command0": MsgBox "Button1 clicked"
        Case "Command1": MsgBox "Button2 clicked"
    End Select
End Sub
```

What is happening is the collection is mimicking, the me.Controls collection in the form, but we are making all our buttons be the class, so thus, using the class _click event.  You could modify the initialise to also take a proc name event, for the sub call, then use application.Run to call the code.

Like so

```
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents cbCustom As CommandButton
Private strProcCall As String

Public Sub INITIALISE(cb As CommandButton, strProc As String)
    Set cbCustom = cb
    strProcCall = strProc
    cb.OnClick = "[Event Procedure]"
End Sub

Private Sub cbCustom_Click()
    Application.Run strProcCall
End Sub
```

and

```
Option Explicit

Public colCustomControls As Collection

Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)

Dim ctl As Control
Dim clsCustom As clsCustomButton

    Set colCustomControls = New Collection

        Set clsCustom = New clsCustomButton
        clsCustom.INITIALISE Me.Controls("Command0"), "MACRO_1"
        colCustomControls.Add clsCustom

        Set clsCustom = New clsCustomButton
        clsCustom.INITIALISE Me.Controls("Command1"), "MACRO_2"
        colCustomControls.Add clsCustom

End Sub
```

Comment: It gives me type match error in this line:
clsCustom.INITIALISE ctl

Comment: Is it just command buttons you're passing or others?   if so you need to check the controls typename before changing to custom

Comment: (I'm kinda new at this language) I managed to fix that but Where do I put the last 2 codes, or I just switch with the other 2? If I can't find anyway to fix that, I can you give you my project and maybe guide me with those names and functions/classes, because I'm getting really confused with that.

Comment: The 2nd codes are a replacement for the 1st, allowing a sub name to be passed also.

Comment: this is a good way to learn, quite well laid out http://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s242/event-sink.htm

Comment: Also, by using a dictionary rather than a collection would allow you to change the function during the use of the form.  Have a play

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can refer to a control with:

```
n = 5
Set ctl = Me("Text" & CStr(n))
```

then *ctl* will refer to *Me!Text5*

But look into *WithEvents*: [How to write generic code ...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31474605/how-to-write-generic-code-to-open-a-form-by-instantiating-the-underlying-class-a/31475644?s=4%7C0.0000#31475644)

Comment: Thank you for answering, I know that I can refer a control, but how do assign that to a button click. (I'm kinda learning this language ^^)